# Script continues on before done downloaing with sftp in bin/expect

Tags: sftp, expect

I have a script that downloads a file from my ssh server. It runs fine and starts downloading fine but it moves on from the download before it finishes. Is there a way for it to wait until the download is done? I have tried wait and it just pauses.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn sftp root@ip
expect "password"
send "<password>\r"

expect "sftp>"
send "lcd Desktop\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd Desktop\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "get -r File\r"
wait
close
wait
```

Answer (score 1):

`expect` will use the `$timeout` setting to give up what it's waiting for, and will continue on with the script. To wait forever until the pattern matches, do

```
set timeout -1
```

So

```
expect "sftp>"
send "get -r File\r"
set timeout -1
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\r"     ;# exit gracefully
expect eof
```